# ¿Por qué reemplaza todo el array? Quiero reemplazo en la posición que asigno

Tags: java

```
public class Arrays_bidimensionales{
  public static void main (String[] args){
    String[][] matriz = { {"b","b"},
                          {"b","b"} };

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
      System.out.println("  ");
      for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " / ");
      }
    }

    String tirada1 = matriz[1][0];
    String tirada2 = matriz[1][0];

    for(int x=0; x<2; x++){
      System.out.println("  ");
      for(int y=0; y<2; y++){
        //String tirada1 = matriz[1][0];
        if(matriz[x][y]==tirada1 && matriz[x][y].equals("b") ){
          matriz[x][y]="M";
        }
      }
    }

    for(int r=0;  r<2; r++){
      System.out.println("  ");
      for(int n=0; n<2; n++){
        System.out.print(matriz[r][n] + " / ");
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es esa posición que le estás asignando?
  
Tienes una matriz de 2x2 y en el segundo **for** estás recorriendo toda esa matriz asignándole el valor de **M** a todo valor que sea igual a **tirada1** (que según asignaste es **b**) y que también sea igual a **b**... y si nos fijamos al inicio, los valores que añadiste al principio, ¡todos son igual a **b**! Esto provocaría que todos los valores que recorras ahora tengan el valor de **M**.

Comment: Estas asignando a las letras a las condiciones de entrada por eso en el for entra en toda las posiciones y remplazas

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código va a cambiar solo en la posición [1][0] cuando tenga una "b" y colocará una "M" que según los datos del ejemplo, siempre va a cumplirse.

Puede declarar dos variables, digamos xPos, yPos, en ellas guardar los índices que luego utilizará para reemplazar en la matriz.

Espero que sea esto lo que necesitaba, se estaba realizando una comparación con el valor y no con la posición dentro de la matriz, por eso reemplaza todo el array.

```
public class Arrays_bidimensionales{
  public static void main (String[] args){
    String[][] matriz = { {"b","b"},
                          {"b","b"} };

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
      System.out.println("  ");
      for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " / ");
      }
    }

    int xPos = 1;
    int yPos = 0;

    /* no serán necesarios
       String tirada1 = matriz[1][0];
       String tirada2 = matriz[1][0]; */

    for(int x=0; x<2; x++){
      System.out.println("  ");
      for(int y=0; y<2; y++){
        if(x == xPos && y == yPos && matriz[x][y].equals("b")){
          matriz[x][y]="M";
        }
      }
    }

    for(int r=0;  r<2; r++){
      System.out.println("  ");
      for(int n=0; n<2; n++){
        System.out.print(matriz[r][n] + " / ");
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`tirada1` es un objeto String con valor "b", al comparar casilla a casilla contra tu `matriz` la comparación`matriz[x][y]==tirada1 && matriz[x][y].equals("b")` siempre regresará `true` por lo que deberías guardar sólo los indices de la posición que deseas reemplazar:

```
int coordenadas[] = {1,0};

if(coordenadas[0]==x && coordenadas[1]==y && matriz[x][y].equals("b") )
    matriz[x][y]="M";
```